# Table cell creates 1px offset on several screen sizes when vertical aligned-top

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having trouble with a 50/50 table-cell Layout - here's the code:

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test<br/>which is even longer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

For easier screen resizing i put it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jnnkm/pen/xOvmKZ/) as well.

**What's the Problem?**

When resizing the viewport the two images which have the same size and are vertical aligned top should be justified. But on several (odd) screen sizes they generate a 1px offset (see screenshot) . Which kind of makes sense because you can't divide an odd pixel value by two, using only integers.
But still this looks bad. Has anyone encountered this problem before and can share a solution?

[image: (see screenshot)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumped by the issue- don't know how to fix it in `table` layouts. But I have solution with `flexbox`es below:

**Flexbox solution**:

Replaced `table` display with a `flexbox`. Check it out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.table-cell {
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test<br/>which is even longer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Another solution**:

Using `inline-block` and `float` with 50% widths:

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.table-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table-wrapper:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=66&txt=700%C3%97500&w=700&h=500">
    <h2>this is a test<br/>which is even longer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! You're example looks great and i might have a go with it, even though in this specific case: I'd prefer a table-layout, so any thoughts on this issue, using display: table; is still appreciated.

Comment: @JannikMüller check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209886/1px-calculation-issue-with-browsers/39210166

Comment: @JannikMüller: looks like this a `sub-pixel issue` and can't be solved using tables... we will have to sort to alternative solutions. check out the new solution I've given above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i think this should be work

```
.table-cell img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;

}
```

Comment: i updated the codepen, still having the same issue :/

Comment: try add vertical-align: top; to .table-cell

Comment: .table-cell { vertical-align: top; } is already in the example