# 1px calculation issue with browsers (sub-pixel problems)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I think this issue is common and picked it up here in SO itself, but could not find how to solve this.

**Problem**:

When you resize the window, you will notice that the height of the two images will differ by 1px at times (that is expected when browser adjusts the dimesions).

How do I 'fix' this UI issue? I know I can do that by using a `flexbox`. But I guess there is a better solution. Could you guys jump in?

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or even here when I use `display: table`:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  display: table;
}
.wrapper div{
  display: table-cell;  
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
</div>
```

**Edit**:
The issue not there in Firefox browser but exists in Chrome.

Note that the issue is not there when I use a `flexbox`:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;  
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div{
  flex: 1;  
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
</div>
```

or using floats and inline-blocks:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;  
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
.wrapper div{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}
.wrapper:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  clear:both;
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tables are meant for tabular data, you should use flexbox or another css choice for images

Comment: acutally i'm looking if there is a solution other than flexboxes as i mentioned in question

Comment: flex is the best choice for something like your html code describes

Comment: @yousefsami `padding` won't work- try resizing the browser

Comment: `img { width: calc(100% + 2px); } ` ?

Comment: @pol no it doesn't :(

Comment: this: https://jsfiddle.net/hhmsqtz6/ ?

Comment: @mlegg if I were to change the markup from `table` to `div`s with similar behaviour, is there an option to prevent this issue without using flexboxes?

Comment: @mlegg would be nice to know what the issue is.

Comment: What browser and version are you using, because I don't see the images differ on resize, nor on load.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange you have already acknowledged the issue by posting an answer and now you deleted the answer saying you are checking why it is still happening after you added a CSS reset?

Comment: @pol using chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit))

Comment: @kukkuz OK, I tried on chrome 52, and I managed to get the images to differ. Though on firefox I couldn't replicate it.

Comment: @pol that's right, I'm not getting issue in firefox 31.0 (just checked), but in chrome

Comment: @kukkuz - what do you want to happen?  If the browser width is 1001px, do you want both images to be sized at 500px wide? and if so, what do you want to happen to that extra 1px? Or do you want one image to be 500px wide and one image to be 501px side, but both should be 500px high?

Comment: Not really sure there is a fix for this. I tried setting it up with a background image, but even then the height difference still appears.

Comment: @andi when I use flexboxes for 1001px in chrome i get 500.5px width each... looking for a similar fix here if it is possible..

Comment: I saw this kind of thing in chrome 2 years ago. Due to your width being a %, there is always going to be a time where the width is odd and the 2 images get 2 different height. You would have to use js to correct the width of both images to be the same at all times

Comment: I don't think you actually get 500.5px each... if you have one image that's red and one that's yellow, are you telling me that the center pixel in the browser would actually be half red and half yellow?

Comment: @andi yes, chrome reports 500.5 each

Comment: I'm not asking what Chrome reports.  I am asking - if you take a screenshot of that page, and then measure the actual image sizes using a tool like Photoshop, what measurements would you get?

Comment: @andi check out the `flexbox` solution I've added to the question. As Oriol says below, `flexbox` breaks the aspect ratio

Comment: @kukkuz - so is that what you want, but from a non-flexbox solution?

Comment: Yes, a non-flexbox solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of [Sub-Pixel Problems](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/).

Each image takes 50% of the container. For example, if the container is 100px wide, each image will be 50px wide.

But the width of container could be an odd number of pixels, e.g. 101px. Then there are three reasonable possibilities:

- Make one image 50px wide and the other 51px. Then the images won't be equally wide, even if you specified the same width to both of them.
- Make both images 50px wide. Then there will be a 1px gap
- Make both images 51px wide. Then they won't fit, overflowing the container or wrapping to the next line.

Each choice has its downsides, but nowadays browsers seem to prefer the first option. However, in this case, the images have an intrinsic aspect ratio, so different widths will produce different heights, and then the 1px gap is created horizontally instead of vertically.

It seems Firefox detects than, and thus makes the smaller image as tall as the other one, breaking the aspect ratio. Chrome prefers to enforce the aspect ratio.

There is no way to change this. It's completely implementation dependent:

> The especially strange part, in all of this, is that there’s really no
>   right, or wrong, here. How this behavior is supposed to play out by
>   the rendering engine isn’t dictated by the CSS specification, having
>   it be left up to the implementation to render as it sees fit.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation :) so I guess flexboxes breaks the aspect ratio? is there an option other than that?

Comment: @kukkuz Since the spec does not specify what should happen in these cases, you can't rely on anything. You can try different approaches and use the one that works as desired for most browsers, but future or past versions could behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

try this responsive image grid code http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/AXZGox
change my img src= to whatever your code will be

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 <img src="http://www.irishtimes.com/polopoly_fs/1.2614603.1461003507!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_620_330/image.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 <img src="http://www.irishtimes.com/polopoly_fs/1.2614603.1461003507!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_620_330/image.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: view the codepen in full screen then slowly resize it down and watch how it keeps the aspect and then stacks the images in narrow width screens

Comment: I use that grid system a lot. Look at this page and you can customize it http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of a different approach to this which might meet your needs... instead of worrying about forcing the image sizes, you can vertically-align everything to the top, and then hide the bottom 1px of the wrapper div by adding a 1px high pseudo-element which is the same color as the background.  This will solve the visual aspect of having images 1px off from each other.  It will also hide the bottom 1px of the images even if they are properly aligned, but depending on your images, this may not be a big deal at all.

```
body {width:501px; background:black;}
.wrapper{width:100%; display:table; position:relative;}
.wrapper:after {content:""; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; height:1px; width:100%; background:black;}
.wrapper div {display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
img {display: block; width:100%;}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4ktweuo/1/

Comment: You're a genius. After playing with it for literally hours, I finally just added a :before with `width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid white;` which overlaps the element and hides any inconsistent sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since chrome doesn't seem to play very well with .5px values.
Here is a javascript solution to make the width always an even number, thus the height will also be even:

https://jsfiddle.net/hhmsqtz6/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeToEven();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeToEven();
});

function resizeToEven() {
  $('tbody').width(function(i, w) {
    var parentwidth = $('tbody').parent().width();
    return (parentwidth - parentwidth % 2);
  });
}
```

```css
table, tbody, tr {
  width: 100% !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: flex; /* I had to made them flex, other display wasn't working */
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

td {
  padding: 0; /* put padding, to remove the gap */
  
  /* set the width, because when right clicking it gets all messed up (at least it did, in my tests) */
  width: 50%;
}

html {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></td>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```