# Unexpected resulting box height

Tags: css

I'm setting:

```
font-size: 13.44px
line-height: 1.4881
```

Multiplying those, [gives us 20.000064](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=13.44%20*%201.4881&oq=13.44%20*%201.4881&gs_l=serp.3..19.20639.25829.0.26075.9.9.0.0.0.0.311.1083.2-3j1.4.0....0...1c.1j2.64.serp..5.1.283.I3tGi3APsQc)

But the rendered/calculated height of the box is 19px

Why?

http://jsbin.com/vokesukeye/2/edit?html,output

Comment: probably it's being rounded, first to font-size 13px and then the result to 19px

Comment: That should be highly unlikely since font size 13.1px is rendered obviously smaller than 13.4px It means that browsers are not throwing away the decimals while rendering.

Comment: Check out the difference between 13.4px and 13.5px in the font-size (resulting 19px and 20px respectively), it is highly probable, that it is rounded on the way

Comment: @AdamWolski I am really confused. Why would the browser round the font size?

Comment: @Birowsky Why not? There is no such thing as a fractional pixel. Line widths are rounded too. You can't have a 0.5 pixel thick line.

Comment: My Chrome inspector is showing a 20.0001px computed value for `line-height`. `line-height` != `height` http://jsbin.com/pebuleyufi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Except on a Retina screen of course...

Comment: @MrLister not true. Font size of 13.1px is being rendered differently than 13.4px on any screen.

Comment: @Birowsky Not here actually. If I add another div to the JSBin with a font size of 13.1px, the results are identical. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrQet.jpg). Which exact browser and OS are you testing on?

Comment: Pardon, @MrLister you are right. I was testing that wrong. Even on retina it's identical. I would accept Johannes as an answer because he was the first to suggest this. Or yours because you tried to teach me.

Comment: @Birowsky I agree with MrLister, you can't have fractional pixels and browsers just seem to show us fractions - see the famed [1px browser issue and how Chrome and Firefox handles them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209886/1px-calculation-issue-with-browsers) to give you an example...

Comment: @MrLister I've got another one for you http://stackoverflow.com/q/40443317/592641

Comment: @Birowsky Since you wrote you would accept my comment as an answer, I added it as an answer now. I saw that you already accepted another answer telling what I had written earlier in my comment, but you can still give me an upvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment earlier: The pixel values are being rounded, first to font-size 13px and then the result to 19px, due to the nature of pixels (which are a whole pixel or no pixel, except possibly on retina displays)

Comment: Even on Retina (and other high-DPI displays), when every virtual pixel is 2x2 real pixels, virtual pixels are treated as binary: either "present" or not. Box shadow might make an exception, but it's not directly controllable by style rules.

Answer (score 4):

The font-size seems to be rounded up or down for this calculation.

When I increase your CSS font-size to 13.6px (via Chrome's "Inspect" function), the text container height was increased from 19px to 20px.

[image]

You may want to try to use "Inspect" with your browser and interactively adjust these CSS settings to determine your CSS settings.