# A border of 1px in chrome and 0.8px in firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I gave a border of 1px to a div under chrome. I can get a border of 1px in developer tools, but when I use firefox to view it, it is only 0.8px. Why? I feel very strange, can you tell me why? Thank you.

```
<div class="friendHeaderFont">
  <label class="dynamic" :class="{active: isClickDynamic}">hello</label>
  <label class="nearBy" :class="{active: !isClickDynamic}">world</label>
</div>

.friendHeaderFont {
  width: 144px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: calc((100% - 100px) / 2);
  top: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC; 
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.dynamic {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.nearBy {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: #DB4139;
  border-radius: 30px;  
}
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n5GC.png)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioPw5.png)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209886/1px-calculation-issue-with-browsers-sub-pixel-problems) out too...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is related to the Windows Display Settings. It happens if you have the Windows Display set at 125% instead of 100%. I had the same problem, changed Windows display to 100% and it was fine. As you said, it seems to be a Firefox problem, Chrome is ok.

See also this Firefox Bug Report:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1427391

On here, they recommend using `box-sizing: border-box` and including the border width in the width of your element.So if the element was 30px with 1px border either side then the width would be 32px now.

Comment: it's 2023 and I'm now having this exact issue in Chrome - so, presumably, this is not a bug, but a feature? what's confusing here is, what's the unit in devtools? since it's clearly not logical pixels, which is what the `px` unit is for - is it in device pixels maybe? kinda makes you wish they had put units on those numbers. 