# CSS grid's slider - Why there is a distortion when I slide my grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-grid

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gqfvpy?file=style.scss

I have created a grid aimed to allow an horizontal sliding. I have spoted that when I slide, the grid appears with some offset compared to the first grid. 
Why when I make my grid slides using the "go {direction}"'s button, the second grid's photos appears with some offset compared to the first grid?

I expect that they appear with exactly same positioning.

How is this possible, since I have expicitly set:

```
display:grid; 
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-auto-columns:calc(50% - #{$column-gap/2});
grid-template-rows:100%;
```

in my `.grid-container` ?

react snippet:

```
    return (
      <div>
       <GridSlider slideView={slideView}/>


        <div className="button-container">
          {

            buttonToDisplay==="left" &&
              <button 
                className="slide-view__button" 
                onClick={this.slideView}
              >  
                      go right
              </button>
          }
          {
            buttonToDisplay==="right" &&
              <button 
                className="slide-view__button" 
                onClick={this.slideView}
              > 
                      go left  
              </button>
          }
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const GridSlider=({slideView})=>(
  <div className="grid-container">
            <div className={`grid ${slideView}`}>
              <div className="grid-item">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509909756405-be0199881695?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div className="grid-item">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509909756405-be0199881695?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"/>
              </div>
              <div className="grid-item">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509909756405-be0199881695?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" />
              </div>
             <div className="grid-item">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509909756405-be0199881695?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div className="grid-item">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509909756405-be0199881695?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"/>
              </div>
{...}
```

SCSS' snippet:

```
.grid-container{
    height:$grid-container-height;
    width:$grid-width;
    max-width: $grid-width;
    //margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;

    display:grid; 
  grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns:calc(50% - #{$column-gap/2});
    grid-template-rows:100%;

    grid-column-gap: $column-gap;
  background: yellowgreen;  
}

.grid-container > div{
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 

    grid-area: span 1/ span 2; 
}

.grid{ 
 height:100%; 
 width:100%; 
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2,1fr);
   grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr); 
  grid-gap:10px 7px;
}

.grid div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  min-width:0;
  min-height:0;
  // background:green;
  border-radius:$border-radius;
}

.grid img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 // background:red;
  border-radius:$border-radius;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: *`I have created a grid aimed to allow an horizontal sliding. I have spoted that when I slide, the grid appears with some offset compared to the first grid`* To me the code works, when i click on the button both grids moves ever so slightly increasing the offset from `-1` to `-1.5` makes it more visible. However to you  there seems to be a problem with this, Which you have failed to explain.

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks for your comment. What precision do you want? Meanwhile I mean that I have spoted that when I slide, the second grid's photos appears with some offset compared to the first grid. I would expect they appear with exactly same positioning, do you observe this phenomenon -specifically on the right of the grid?

Comment: clicking on Go is doing nothing, is your code up to date?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have updated it, would uyou mind to try again?

Comment: it"s working and see no offset, both seems to behave the same .. maybe add a screenshot of the issue

Comment: This is only visible on FF and it looks like it depends on adding `null` class

Comment: @Xesenix effectively I am on Mozilla Firefox 68.9.0esr, interesting what do you mean by adding `null` class please?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62340069/9060223) help?

Answer (score 1):

### Sizes

The pure mathematical value calculated from your `translateX(calc(-1 * (60vw + 10vh)))` is already **correct**. I will list some numbers that are computed from your relative values (percentages, `vw`s and `vh`s) with the `body` size being `705px, 523.367px` with margin `8px`.

- The elements (`.grid-item`) inside your class `.grid` have a size of `102.9px, 213.083px`
- The gap between each `.grid-item` is `7px`, as you specified explicitly with a fixed unit
- The transform value of `calc(-1 * (60vw + 10vh))` is `-499.7px`

---

### Rendering

As you can see from the above sizes, a lot of your elements have some very weird decimal points (e.g. `.083`, `.9`, and `.7`). **One pixel** is actually the smallest unit. Howver, modern browsers have ways to implement how to render elements with decimal point sizes (subpixel units). We're not going to discuss how browsers handle this. What we know is that [when elements are rendered with decimal point values, it can cause a marginally erroneous rendering, often only by one pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211150/9060223) (which is often negligible). In your case, the offset of one pixel seems unpleasant.

The *subpixel rendering implementation* of each browser is different. As mentioned, this causes erroneous rendering. So the obvious solution is to simply **round** the decimal values to the nearest integer. Unfortunately for us, your example uses `vw` and `vh`. This means that the `vw` values, for instance the `60vw` you used on the SASS variable `$grid-width`, will only be resolved until **after the sizes of the viewport is resolved** (*I can't find the link where I found this)*, but your CSS is compiled before then. Using [`round` (a SASS function)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math) here simply doesn't work.

There's nothing much we can do about subpixel rendering. We can only try to avoid it or work around the problem.

---

### Solution

Instead of making the `.grid-container` with `display: grid`, we can opt to display the contents as flexbox. Each grid spans the full width of `.grid-container` and also the full height of `.grid-container`. Only one grid is shown at a time and each grid is wrapped into the next row of the flexbox. Using `translateY` and a value of the multiplication of `-100%`, we can show the n-th grid inside the `.grid-container`.

The changes you need to make are simply in the `.grid-container` class, `.grid` class, and `.slide-view` class. Here's [the runnable code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cx68br).

```
.grid-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: $grid-container-height;
  width:$grid-width;
  max-width: $grid-width;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellowgreen;  
}

.grid{ 
  height:100%; 
  width:100%; 
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr); 
  grid-gap:10px 7px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.slide_view{ 
  transform: translateY(-100%) /* 0% to show the first grid, -100% to show the second grid, and so forth */; 
}
```